# Calling class methods from a module that is included by that class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multiple-inheritance

In the code below, I would like to call the class method `done` of the class that includes the module from inside `self.hello`

Explanation:

`A::bonjour` will call `Mod::hello` so will `B::ciao`

I would like to be able to detect the "calling class" (A or B) in `Mod::hello`  in order to be able to call the `A::done` or `B::done`

```
module Mod
 def self.hello
  puts "saying hello..."
 end
end

class A
 include Mod

 def self.bonjour
  Mod::hello 
 end

 def self.done
  puts "fini"
 end
end

class B
 include Mod

 def self.ciao
  Mod::hello
 end

 def self.done
  puts "finitto"
 end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While (perhaps) not as clean as Niklas' answer, it's still easily doable, and IMO cleaner than the usage pattern shown in the OP which relies on knowing which module is mixed in.

(I prefer not having to pass an argument to mixin methods like this when other means exist.)

The output:

```
pry(main)> A::bonjour
saying hello...
fini
pry(main)> B::ciao
saying hello...
finitto
```

The guts:

```
module Mod
  module ClassMethods
    def hello
      puts "saying hello..."
      done
    end
  end

  def self.included(clazz)
    clazz.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

The modified class declarations, removing the explicit module reference:

```
class A
  include Mod

  def self.bonjour
    hello
  end

  def self.done
    puts "fini"
  end
end

class B
  include Mod

  def self.ciao
    hello
  end

  def self.done
    puts "finitto"
  end
end
```

You may also supply a default implementation of `done`:

```
module Mod
  module ModMethods
    def hello
      puts "saying hello..."
      done
    end

    def done
      throw "Missing implementation of 'done'"
    end
  end

  def self.included(clazz)
    clazz.extend ModMethods
  end
end
```

---

As a comment to this post points out, if the snippet in the OP is a faithful representation of the actual usecase, you might as well use `extend` (instead of `include`), leaving everything cleaner:

```
module Mod
  def hello
    puts "saying hello..."
    done
  end

  def done
    raise NotImplementError("Missing implementation of 'done'")
  end
end
```

And the classes using `extend`:

```
class A
  extend Mod

  def self.bonjour
    hello
  end

  def self.done
    puts "fini"
  end
end
```

Comment: Use extend, using include and a ClasssMethods is an anti-pattern usually, especially when there are no "instance methods".

Comment: @Monouïe While I agree, I was attempting to follow at least part of the OP's pattern. (Plus ultimately I'm not sure that the OP wasn't just a simplified example. I'll update the answer, however.)

Comment: Thanks, @Monouïe :-) Thank you for your answer Dave =) The original answer is very informational and the updated one is what I was looking for =)

Comment: Also, throw in Ruby is not the same as in e.g. C++. You want raise, also with a proper exception class (in this case NotImplementedError would be perfetly suitable).